# approximate matching using grep

Tags: unix, grep, matching

I need to create a script that loops through files in a directory, check if the filename is in "list.txt" then process it. My problem is that the filenames are dynamic since it has timestamp.

Is there a way to grep approximate match in unix?

Sample.

```
list.txt
SAMPLE_REPORT_1
SAMPLE_REPORT_2
```

Report Filenames

```
SAMPLE_REPORT_1_20180416121345.csv
SAMPLE_REPORT_2_20180416121645.csv
```

I need to check if the filenames are in list.txt

Comment: sorry. I meant "files in a directory". corrected my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`bash`** + **`grep`** solution:

```
for f in *.csv; do
    if grep -qx "${f%_*.csv}" list.txt; then
        # processing file $f 
    fi
done
```

Comment: this works great. thanks! may I ask  how to handle if I need to loop through xls file as well?

Comment: I already got this part   `for f in {*.csv,*.xls*}`. Im trying to figure out how to add the xls in this line `grep -qx "${f%*.csv}"`

Comment: think i got it using this `grep -qx -e "${f%*.csv}" -e "${f%*.xls*}"`